# Python - non-default argument follows

Tags: python-3.x

I just started to learn `Python` and I was trying to code a function, where the user will be asked to input `j/J/ja or Ja` for `True` and `n/N/nein or Nein` for `False`.

Here is the code:

```
def ask_ok(prompt, retries=4, complaint="Ja oder Nein!", abc):
    while True:
        ok = input(prompt)
        if ok in ('j', 'J', 'ja', 'Ja'): abc = True
        if ok in ('n', 'N', 'nein', 'Nein'): abc = False
        retries = retries - 1
        if abc is True:
            print ("Its True")
            return True
        elif abc is False:
            print("Its False")
            return False
        elif retries < 0:
            raise IOError('Keine Fags erlaubt!')
        print(complaint)


ask_ok("Willst du wirklich aufhören?\n")
```

PyCharm show me the error:

```
line 1
    def ask_ok(prompt, retries=4, complaint="Ja oder Nein!", abc):
              ^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

Hope for your help.

Comment: `abc` must have a default value or be located before `retries`

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. You have a non-default argument (`abc`) after a couple of default aurguments (`retries`, `complaint`). That's not allowed in Python.

Comment: Thank you, I solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

In a function definition's list of arguments, the ones with a default value (such as, `retries=4`, must be the last. If you change your definition to `def ask_ok(prompt, abc, retries=4, complaint="Ja oder Nein!"):` you should be okay.

This reduces ambiguity when calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def ask_ok(prompt, abc=0, retries=4, complaint="Ja oder Nein!"):
    while True:
        ok = input(prompt)
        if ok in ('j', 'J', 'ja', 'Ja'): abc = True
        if ok in ('n', 'N', 'nein', 'Nein'): abc = False

        retries = retries - 1
        if abc is True:
            print ("Its True")
            return True
        elif abc is False:
            print("Its False")
            return False
        elif retries < 0:
            raise IOError('Keine Fags erlaubt!')
        print(complaint)


ask_ok("Willst du wirklich aufhören?\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, arguments with default value must appear, only after all the positional arguments have been specified in the function prototype declaration.

So, your function prototype declaration must look like given below :-

```
def ask_ok(prompt, abc, retries=4, complaint="Ja oder Nein!"):
   # your code
```

Moreover, for your information, you must avoid using default arguments values as default values, as they are created only once and they'll be shared between each function call :-

eg.

```
def sampleFunc(arg1=[]):
   arg1.append(23)
   print arg1

sampleFunc(1)  # prints [1]
sampleFunc(23) # prints [1, 23]
```

This non-obvious thing generally confuses several novice programmer to python

Comment: Specify reason for downvoting.